# Load content within div without refreshing main page

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, dynamic, embed

Hello i have a 3 pages i want to run within one main page (`index.html`) sort of "app style"

the pages are:  `form.html`, the form `results.php` and a `link.html` page

i want it to load like this demo: removed (site down) but not using embed or iframe.

Once the form on `form.html` is submitted it goes to the `results.php` page and that page pretends to load and then after 5 seconds or so it goes to the  `link.html` page And i want this all to happen without reloading `index.html`

I have looked at dynamic pages & trying to hide/show things using jQuery 
But i can't seem to get anything to work with the timer and the form submit making things hard for me.

Any help would be Unbelievably Appreciated I've been messing around with this for awhile and i only really know html and css and have only played around with JavaScript and php a bit.

I would be great to see some-working code with a form and timer using the script below. but even getting pointed in the right direction could be helpful. thanks & sorry if this question not appropriate for this site.

My code: `index.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>index main page</title>
      <style>
         /** http://cssreset.com */html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {    margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}
         body{
             background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/z69OCGn.png);
             background-repeat:repeat; 
             height:100%;
             width:100%;
             position:fixed;
         }
         #wrap{
             background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/Xuyys5X.png);
             background-repeat:repeat; 
             width:800px;
             height:100%;
         }
         #header{
             width:600px;
             height:100px;
         }
         #load{
             background-color:#fff;
             margin-top:100px;
             width:600px;
             height:300px;
         }
         .centre{
             margin-left:auto;
             margin-right:auto;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrap" class="centre">
         <div id="header">
            </br></br></br></br>
            <p align="center" style="color:#fff;"> The Page doesn't refresh or reload </p>
         </div>
         <div id="load" style=""  class="centre">
            <embed src="form.html" width="600px" height="300px" style="border:1px solid">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

`form.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page 1</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div3">
         <div id="form">
            <form action="results.php" method="post" >
               <input id="field" name="field" required>
               <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

`result.php`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page 2</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function countdown() {
             var i = document.getElementById('counter');
             if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)>=100) {
                 location.href = 'link.html';
                 clearInterval(t);
                 exit;
             }
             i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)+1;
         }
         var t = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },100);
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div1">
         <p>this will be displayed on the results page. its not, just for reference. </p>
         <p>Submit: </p>
         <font color="#33CC00"><?php echo $_POST["field"]; ?> </font>
         <div style="margin-left:55px; margin-top:20px;">
            <p>Page change in: <font color="#33CC00"><span id="counter"> 10</span></font></p>
         </div>
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LLzENHe.gif">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

`link.html`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page 3</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div3">
         <p>this is a link <a href="#">Link</a></p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by having three divs with say ids as '#home-page', '#result-page' and 'link-page'. Keep the last two pages hidden. Then make an ajax call on form submit and display the response to the #result-page div and hide the form. After few secs, you show the #link-page and hide the #result-page.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/5/) for you. I hope this is what you want.

#### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="results.php"> 
    <h2>Form Page</h2>
    Your form elements here
</form>
<div id="result-page" style="display:none">
    <h2>Result Page:</h2>
    Result of the ajax call here
</div>
<div id="link-page" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Link page:</h2>
    Link page content here
</div>
```

On load of page, attach an event for form submit where in you make an ajax call and append the response into the result-page div

#### JS

```
$("form[ajax=true]").submit(function (e) {
$.ajax({
        url: 'results.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result-page").append(data).show(); // appending data response to result-page div
            $('form').hide();  //hiding form
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#result-page").hide(); 
                $("#link-page").show();
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted, thanks so much for taking your time to do this for me, i really appreciate it! especially with the jsfiddle demo too! Thanks again! hope you have had a good day :)

Comment: Im having a little trouble try to "localizing" the script off  jsfiddle? any ideas?

Comment: you need to change the attribute action="/echo/html/" to name of a file that the form is submitted to

Comment: yes but its seem to load that file/page then? can't it submit on it's self? does this have something to do with the link div not load or is that another issue?

Comment: I don't know if I got you right. Are you saying after submit, it doesn't stay on the same page? Also can you update that link you gave with proper action you will be using so that I can see the issue.

Comment: check if the field is recieved in php as in the success method 'responsehtml' is blank.

Comment: Its says: returnhtml if i change it to blank, it just loads forever on the submit form.

Comment: What I meant is do a print_r in the results.php and check if the file recieves the data submitted.

Comment: thanks comes up with " Array ( [html] => demotext ) " demotext being what i wrote in the form.

Comment: ok cool. [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) prints the array. Replace that with [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Hope this solves everything

Comment: Yeap thanks heaps used: <?php echo $_POST["html"]; ?> and works great thanks for all you help, i really really do appreciate it :)